# What is the most efficient way to pass a non generic function?

Tags: c++, function, functor, std-function

I am learning functional programming in C++. My intention is to pass a non generic function as argument. I know about the template method, however I would like to restrict the function signature as part of the API design. I worked out 4 different methods [example on cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/2wds):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

typedef int(functor_type)(int);


int by_forwarding(functor_type &&x)  {
    return x(1);
}

int functor_by_value(functor_type x) {
    return x(1);
}

int std_func_by_value(std::function<functor_type> x) {
    return x(1);
}

int std_func_by_forwarding(std::function<functor_type> &&x) {
    return x(1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << functor_by_value([](int a){return a;}); // works
    std::cout << std_func_by_value([](int a){return a;}); // works
    std::cout << std_func_by_forwarding(std::move([](int a){return a;})); // works

    //std::cout << by_forwarding([](int a){return a;}); // how to move lambda with forwarding ?
}
```

Is any of the above attempts correct? If not, how do i achieve my goal?

Comment: `prog.cc:29:41: warning: moving a temporary object prevents copy elision ` :) clang warnings ftw!

Comment: Short answer: `int functor_by_value(functor_type x)`.

Comment: `std::invoke` if you have access to C++17

Comment: Lambdas are anonymous, therefore you can only grab its type through type deduction.

Comment: It depends on meaning you put into "pass a non generic function" First two variants accept a reference or a pointer to function. 3rd and 4th variant accept an object or an rvalue reference to object with overloaded `operator ()`. So every `x` has an `operator ()` so usual calling syntax `x(1);` works, however none of them are functions.

Comment: What do you mean by a "non generic" function? There are no generic functions in C++ in any sense of "generic" that I'm aware of (although some might refer to function templates as generic functions). From the examples, it seems like you're referring to lambdas.

Comment: By "non generic" I mean a function that has a type restriction. In my example it is `int(int)`. This type shall be defined on the API side. A practical application would be to accept a handler callback function `f(SpecificResponseType handle)`. To my understanding, if I use Jarod42's definition (in his answer), I could pass any function, resulting in a runtime error.

Comment: As a side note. 1) In `int by_forwarding(functor_type &&x)`  `functor_type&&` is not a forwarding reference it is a rvalue refence, so  "by forwarding" part is wrong. 2) You should not use `std::move` on temporaries. You probably should read about "`std::move` being a cast and not moving anything"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(based on clarification from comments)

Signature can be restricted by using `std::is_invocable`:

```
template<typename x_Action> auto
functor_by_value(x_Action && action)
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<int, x_Action, int>);
    return action(1);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lViB87onXwLbu08f)

Comment: @lubgr Just a habit. I've been working in environment that prohibits implicit object construction.

Answer (score 5):

Other alternative:

```
template <typename Func>
auto functor_by_value(Func&& f)
-> decltype(std::forward<Func>(f)(1))
{
    return std::forward<Func>(f)(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As usual, this depends on how good your compiler is today, and how good it will be in the future.

Currently, compilers are not very good at optimizing `std::function`. Surprisingly, `std::function` is a complicated object that sometimes has to allocate memory to maintain stateful lambda functions. It also complicates matters that `std::function` has to be able to refer to member function, regular functions, and lambdas, and do it in a transparent manner. This transparency has a hefty runtime cost.

So, if you want the fastest possible code, you should be careful with `std::function`. For that reason the first variant is the fastest (on today's compilers):

```
int functor_by_value(functor_type x) {
    return x(1);
}
```

It simply passes a pointer to a function.

When stateful lambdas are involved you have only two options. Either pass the lambda as a template argument, or convert to `std::function`. Hence, if you want the fastest code possible with lambdas (in today's compilers), you'd pass the function as a templated argument.

Since a lambda function may have a big state, passing it around may copy the big state (when copy elision is not possible). GCC will construct the lambda directly on the parameter list (with no copy), but a nested function will invoke a copy constructor for the lambda. To avoid that, either pass it by const reference (in that case it can't be mutable), or by rvalue reference:

```
template<class Func>
void run2(const Func & f)
{
    std::cout << "Running\n";
    f();
}
template<class Func>
void run(const Func & f)
{
    run2(f);
}
int main()
{
    run([s=BigState()]() { std::cout << "apply\n"; });
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
template<class Func>
void run2(Func && f)
{
    f();
}
template<class Func>
void run(Func && f)
{
    run2(std::forward<Func>(f));
}
int main()
{
    run([s=BigState()]() { std::cout << "apply\n"; });
    return 0;
}
```

Without using references, the BigState() will be copied when the lambda is copied.

**UPDATE:**
After reading the question again I see that it wants to restrict the signature

```
template<typename Func, 
         typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible_v<decltype(Func(1)), int>>>
void run2(const Func & f)
{
    std::cout << "Running\n";
    f();
}
```

This will restrict it to any function that can accept `int` (possibly with an implicit cast), and returns an `int` or any type that is implicitly cast to `int`. However, if you want to accept only function-like objects that accept  exactly `int` and return exactly int you can see if the lambda is convertible to `std::function<int(int)>`

Answer (score 5):

> however I would like to restrict the function signature as part of the API design.

So restrict it:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

/// @tparam F is a type which is callable, accepting an int and returning an int
template
<
    class F, 
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        std::is_convertible_v<F, std::function<int(int)>>
    >* = nullptr
>
int myfunc(F &&x) {
    return x(1);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = myfunc([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; return 1; });

    // does not compile
    // auto b = myfunc([]() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; return 1; });
}
```

Comment: This would fail when object can be invoked as `int (int)` but can not be converted to `std::function` object. [For example when object is not copyable / movable but has `public: int operator ()(int)`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ktOE29JgZyMtSdAM).

Comment: @VTT I do agree - std::function expects function objects to be callable on the const interface, which may or may not be a bug in the standard, depending on how you look at it. However, the OP mentioned that std::function was a candidate for the argument type, so I took a lead from there. I saw your answer (and upvoted). I was not aware of the is_invocable_r_t type trait.